# Cannot set timezone to "+60" in jQuery UI datetimepicker add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using the [jQuery UI datetimepicker add-on v.1.6.3](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to set up an input field with a date and time picker widget. [According to the documentation](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-options), one is supposed to specify the timezone being used in the picker by setting the offset in minutes for the `timezone` option (e.g. `120` or `-360`).

This works fine for me for all offsets that I specify except for `60` - when I use this number as offset, the widget ignores it and switches to my local timezone's offset instead (currently `+0200`) which is, according to the docs,  presumably the `if null is passed` behaviour.

Especially interesting is the fact that this only occurs when my system (Windows 7) is in my local `+0200` timezone - when I switch to a different local timezone via the system settings, it works as expected.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbgf1kab/2/) showing this in effect. If your system is not in timezone `+0200` then you will probably see the correct value - however, you might want to switch to that timezone to observe the problem.

If you cannot/do not want to switch your timezone settings, see this screenshot showing the effect on my machine:
[image]

Any clue what can be done about this?

Comment: This looks more like a localization issue than a problem with the widget. Try `'Z'` format instead of `'z'` to confirm. If this is the case - a possible solution would be to set `timezoneList` manually

Comment: Same result with the `'Z'` format. Besides, I found [this bug ticket](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/840) which sounds pretty similar.

However, using a custom `timezoneList` option during the datetimepicker initialization together with the intended offset in minutes (-> 60) for the `timezone` option works indeed, thank you for the hint! You also might want to add this as an answer since it is an easy work around for the problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it either from your fiddle or from the linked bug ticket (which is why I suggested it's a localization prob) I don't feel comfortable writing an answer without a better understanding the problem; but i'd encourage you to post an answer yourself about how you dealt with it. It may be useful to someone in the future